# Перегрузка операторов C++. Присвоение массива.

Tags: перегрузка-операторов, c++

В C++11 классу vector можно присвоить массив вида

```
std::vector < int > a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Как требуется перегрузить оператор присваивания для достижения такого эффекта (если это вообще возможно)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем структуры и так поддерживают подобное поведение изначально.

А если нужно добавить такое поведение в свой класс, то вот пример небольшой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class A
{
public:
    A(std::initializer_list<int> list)
    {
        for(auto& item : list)
        {
            std::cout << "item=" << item << "\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a{23,321,321,3,213,213,12};
};
```

Пример взял вот здесь: http://scrutator.me/post/2012/11/16/new-ctors-p1.aspx

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 1):

В примере не присваивание а инициализация. Нельзя написать так:

```
std::vector < int > a;
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Почувствуйте разницу.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы. Не сразу смекнул. В таком случае требуется переформулировать вопрос. Как реализовать конструктор?

Comment: и конструктора такого (с фигурными скобками) тоже не создадите. все что на ум пришло похожее на конструктор с бесконечным числом аргументов. пример: A(...){} - три точки это реальный бесконечный параметр так и пишится

Comment: Ответ @deterok оказался верным.

Comment: где у него знак равно в создания объекта? чем хуже обычный конструктор типа а(1,2,3); ?

Comment: Возможно мы друг друга не поняли. Я не правильно изначально сформулировал вопрос. Я имел ввиду конструктор, а написал про присваивание. Ответ @deterok предоставил конструктор, который может принимать в качества аргумента следующую структуру. А обычный конструктор ничем не хуже, просто реализация через ... мне не очень нравится.

Comment: ну да я на 99м стандарте пишу. мой компилятор такой код не проглотит, а вот мой пример на (...) будет работать на любом компиляторе и не засоряет код сложными конструкциями - это как бонус )